# STM32 and 4-wire resistive touch screen

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32, touchscreen

I'm trying to interface a 4-wire resistive touchscreen to a STM32F429 Discovery board but I can't figure out how it works. I want the MCU to detect a touch so I configured the 4 pins like this:

```
X+ --> input w/pullup connected to EXTI external interrupt 
X- --> input floating (tristated)
Y+ --> input floating (tristated)
Y- --> output to GND
```

in this configuration I should be able to detect a touch and trigger an interrupt on the EXTI line so I can enter a ISR and sample the x and y values with the ADC. But when I connect the X- pin the X+ pin goes to near GND. It seems like current flows between X+ and X- (so the X- is not tristated?).
Here's the code I use to configure the GPIO pins:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef gpio;
gpio.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_1;
gpio.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
gpio.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);

gpio.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
gpio.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
gpio.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);

gpio.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
gpio.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &gpio);

HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

/* initialization using registers, works the same as above */

//  /* Xr and Yu open (input floating) */
//  GPIOA->MODER &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODE2 | GPIO_MODER_MODE1);
//  GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD2 | GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD1);
//
//  /* Xl input with pull-up */
//  GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE0;
//  GPIOA->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD0_0;
//
//  /* Yd to GND (output set to 0) */
//  GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_0;
//  GPIOA->ODR &= ~GPIO_ODR_OD5;
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong or how to configure the tristated pins correctly so they don't pull down the X+ pin.

Answer (score 4):

Between selecting the touch event and reading the touch position, you must reconfigure the pins. The following is from an NXP application note ([AN10675](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10675.pdf)), but applies to any microcontroller and can be adapted to STM32:
[image]

The outputs are set to provide a voltage source for the analogue measurement of the effective voltage divider formed by the touch position:

[image]

On the STM32 it is of course important not to use the GPIO configuration lock feature on these pins as you need three different configurations to read a single touch position event.

Comment: Yes, I read that application note too. But my issue is different. I need to detect the touch (first configuration) and when I configure the pins to do that (the code I provided) the pin behaviour is not what I expect. When the X- and Y+ pins are configured as input with no pull up (tristated) the signal on X+ goes to near zero. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: @Luca : So it is a floating high impedance input; what would you expect to read?  Your question is then about electronics principles, not software, and therefore not for SO.  If your touch driver does not actually work, then you are probably asking an XY question, and not the question you need to ask.

Comment: it's a high impedance floating pin connected to an input pin with pull up resistor to Vcc. In the application you linked it says that to detect a touch I have to configure X+ as input with pullup and X- as input floating (high impedance, tristated). But when I configure the pins like that the X+ pin is automatically pulled to GND (by X-). So I would like to know how to configure the pins correctly.

Comment: @Luca Apologies, I misread your comment.  Will think on that.  Is it perhaps the touchscreen that is pulling it down?  What is the level with the touchscreen not connected?

Comment: @Clifford I've disconnected the touch strip from the LCD and I'm finding issues with driving the pins of the stm32f429 board. If I select two pins as input pullup, one reads 2.50V and the other 0. Same when I try to drive them as output push-pull, some are ok, some don't rise above 0.5 V.
So I think the problem is with the STM32 pins.

Comment: @Luca. It is very unlikely to be a uC problem.

Comment: See my answer [over there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354693/interfacing-a-four-wire-resistive-touch-screen-with-stm32f429discovery/354849#354849)

Comment: @luca : You have accepted berendi's answer on EE, and it appears it was not a software issue.  You should close this question.  Obviously the pins won't behave correctly if they are not available for use on the board!

Comment: @Clifford yes, it was that simple, but I was overlooking it. I'm closing the question.